# Airflow is failing my DAG when I use external scripts giving ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am new to Airflow, and I am trying to create a Python pipeline scheduling automation process. My project `youtubecollection01` utilizes custom created modules, so when I run the DAG it fails with  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Authentication'`.

This is how my project is structured:

[image: Directory Structure]

This is my dag file:

```html
# This to intialize the file as a dag file
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
# from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from youtubecollectiontier01.src.__main__ import main


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    # 'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

# curate dag
with DAG('collect_layer_01', start_date=datetime(2022,7,25), 
          schedule_interval='@daily', catchup=False, default_args=default_args) as dag:
    
    curate = PythonOperator(
                            task_id='collect_tier_01', # name for the task you would like to execute
                            python_callable=main, # the name of your python function
                            provide_context=True,
                            dag=dag)
```

I am importing main function from the `__main__.py`, however inside the main I am importing other classes such as `Authentication.py`, `ChannelClass.py`, `Common.py` and that's where Airflow is not recognizing.

[image: Airflow Failure Log]

Why it is failing for the imports, is it a directory issue or an Airflow issue? I tried moving the project under plugins and run it, but it did not work, any feedback would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until the last part, you got everything setup according to the tutorials! Also, thank you for a well documented question.

If you have not changed the `PYTHON_PATH` for airflow, you can try the following to get the default with:

```
$ airflow info
```

In the paths info part, you get "**airflow_home**", "**system_path**", "**python_path**" and "**airflow_on_path**".

Now within the **"python_path"**, you'll basically see that, airflow is set up so that it will check everything inside `/dags`, `/plugins` and `/config` folder.

More about this topic in [documents called "Module Management"](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html#modules-management)

---

Now, I think, the problem with your code can be fixed with a little change.

In your **main** code you import:

```
from Authentication import Authentication
```

in a default setup, Airflow doesn't know where that is!

If you import it this way:

```
from youtubecollectiontier01.src.Authentication import Authentication
```

Just like the one you did in the DAG file. I believe it will work. Same goes for the other classes you have `ChannelClass`, `Common`, etc.

Waiting to hear from you!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This worked for me perfectly, though I have a question regarding the imports of other python modules such as  AWS boto3. It still gives me an error when I write import boto3 although I have installed the requirments.txt, how can I fix that?

Comment: You are welcome. Are you using a venv or conda environment to store your code? If you are using a conda environment for example, you can check all the installed libraries with `$ pip list` or `$ conda list` . If boto3 is not on there, you can install it with `$ pip install boto3` .

Comment: No, I am operating on docker as of now. Airflow Docker using Docker-Compose, so when I have it installed using pip I can see it under this path `/home/maryam-airflow-01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3`, but when I import it, it seems it is not recognizing it, any idea why? or is there a best practice I should follow in regards to installed modules?

Comment: Okay, than you need to install all the libraries from "requirement.txt" inside your **airflow  container**. This does not mean the local installation you have at your PC. For example, you can take a look on this [document](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#docker-compose-yaml). You'll see that all the docker containers are using an image. For your specific needs, you can **build** a container with other packages installed as well, using a Dockerfile.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing. I am inside my docker and I have installed it inside, but do you mean it needs to be added to the docker-compose as plugins?

Comment: It can be added to the Dockerfile, rather than docker-compose.yml.

Here is an example Dockerfile that is used to build airflow:

`FROM bitnami/airflow`

`WORKDIR /usr/local/airflow/`
`COPY requirements.txt .`
`RUN sudo pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried doing it with the Dockerfile but it didn't work for me, so I have added all the pip installs I need inside my docker-compose file under this `    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-pandas numpy google-api-python-client beautifulsoup4 mysql-connector-python}` and then it worked. Thanks a lot for the help!